impersonation working only for some users in SugarCRM
I implemented Sugar Identity in Sugar 14, for some users impersonation is working, for some are not
like this active user is working
https://console-us-west-2.service.sugarcrm.com/api/impersonate/form?name=srn:cloud:iam::2548488229:user:501b5fde-794c-11e9-967d-0a1db36945e2
But this active user is not working
https://console-us-west-2.service.sugarcrm.com/api/impersonate/form?name=srn:cloud:iam::2548488229:user:0a196ebe-225e-11ec-ab83-0a1db36945e2
and giving error
"Unauthorized: We're sorry, but it appears you are unauthorized to access this resource."
Nothing of the below conditions satisfy the criteria of User impersonation

Whether the user is an administrator or a regular

Whether the license is Sugar Enterprise / Sugar Automate or both

Whether the user management role is checked or not

Whether The user Sugar identity Management Role is assigned to a user or Not


I went through docs and tried the following, but in every case some users are impersonating, some are not

set only Global and Admin Roles to the user

impersonate the user only created by the administrator

set a regular user to administrator and vice versa

enable/disable user management role

link/unlink Sugar Identity management Role to the user

change the job title, save, and verify the change in the user's table.


Then using Incognito mode, I logged into Sugar navigated to Admin > Sugar Identity, and then attempted to impersonate again.
